# How to add padding/margin bottom to a fixed sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've successfully set up my fixed scrolling sidebar following this [tutorial](http://techbrij.com/fixed-sidebar-scrolling-jquery-div).

The only thing I'm having trouble with is adding either padding/margin to the bottom of the sidebar. Currently it lines up flush with the bottom of the viewport and I'd like it to be say 100px; off the bottom.

I'm not sure if I need to edit the JS or if this is something I can achieve with CSS?

Heres my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/23/)

JS

```
$(function () {

var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;

  if (!msie6 && $('.sidebar-container').offset()!=null) {
    var top = $('.sidebar-container').offset().top - parseFloat($('.sidebar-container').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var height = $('.sidebar-container').height();
    var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var gap = 7;
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
      // what the y position of the scroll is
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();

      // whether that's below the form
      if (y+winHeight >= top+ height+gap && y+winHeight<=footerTop) {
        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('.sidebar-container').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top',winHeight-height-gap +'px');
```

Comment: Play with the variable `gap`, but then, you need to adjust the code since it doesnt stick at the good place.

Comment: Thats seems to have done it, thanks for helping with that.